# What is the alternative for SmartTags in Microsoft Office Word addin 2013?

Tags: ms-word, add-in, office-js, office-addins

Since SmartTags (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/284927/description-of-the-smart-tags-in-word) are deprecated in Word 2010, what alternatives are there when developing an addin on Office Word 2013?
The operations of highlighting and tagging words using the Office Word Addin TaskPane 2013 does not seem to be an alternative.

Comment: Why is it tagged outlook-addin, the question is about Word? Could you please describe the scenario better - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have added a link to SmartTags and made it more explicit on the tags. It is related to building a Task Pane in Word 2013 and trying to see if there is any alternative for SmartTags which helps highlighting words and taking action on them in MS Word